# Service Bus Application with Service Bus Project doesn' appear on JDeveloper

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, jdeveloper, servicebus, osb

I'm new to **JDeveloper**, and I need to learn these tools for my job application test.

I'm just installed **JDeveloper** after downloaded the file from [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/downloads/index.html), and now I want to create the hello world service osb 12c.

Following this [documentions](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/cloud/sscs/CreatingOSBApp/creating-a-service-bus-app.html#section1) there on **Creating an Oracle Service Bus Application** section on step 2, there we should adding **Service Bus Application with Service Bus Project**, but on my **JDeveloper** that options don't appear, like this:

[image]

There is no **Service Bus Application with Service Bus Project** options like the documentation.

So, how to adding that..?, where I can find that option..?

Answer (score 1):

You need to download correct JDeveloper version.

I suggest **V886439-01_1of2** and **V886439-01_2of2**:
[image]